# how decorrelating image effect image classification?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification

How decorrelating image effect image classification?
In many website, they use whitening(decorrelating image) for image preprocessing.
What is the benefit?
In machine learning, decorrelation data can calculate easily?

Answer (score 1):

Whitening can be seen as the process of removing the mean values, the correlation between pixel to keep only interesting data. That way, the ML algorithm only sees interesting data and can train faster and more efficiently.

Here are some useful links to understand why whitening can be useful :

[Standford - PCA whitening](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/PCAWhitening/)

[Statistical whitening](http://joelouismarino.github.io/blog_posts/blog_whitening.html)

[Exploring ZCA and color image whitening](https://www.kaggle.com/nicw102168/exploring-zca-and-color-image-whitening)